# Directory engine in PHP to host files from that directory

Tags: php, directory

I'm looking for a sort of directory engine (preferably in PHP) which allows to serve files from that directory to the clients. The directory may contain files of different types. The files may be organized in a hierarchy using sub-directories.

The solution I'm looking for should be able to build a view from such a directory structure with downloadable links to the files, file descriptions, custom thumbnails. The thumbnails could be possible to assign manually for files and directories, they shouldn't be generated automatically. The sub-directories  treated as the categories so it should allow some kind of navigation between them.

The view should be highly customizable, allowing to change layout and look & feel.
I like how the information is presented at the following page:
http://www.doctohelp.com/SuperProducts/ChartWinForms/Chart+Types/

I searched the web but haven't found any appropriate solution at the moment. Mostly there are flat file managers which don't support meta-data or lack for customization.

Is someone aware of such a thing? I would be thankful for any link to already existent solution or some advise on of what components the solution can be built.

Comment: _I searched the web but haven't found..._ Generally it is a good idea to note a few that you found, and why you rejected each - so that people don't re-suggest them.

Comment: Downvoted, as you've asked a question and then abandoned it (your last visit was June 21).

Comment: Thanks @shadowmaan; down-vote removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd put a vote in for [ResourceSpace](http://www.resourcespace.org/). I've not used it yet, but am considering integrating it into one of my projects. It appears to have meta data, has a customisable look and feel, and contains previewers for a lot of file types.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://gallery.sf.net

Its an image library in php but can be used for any kind of files. Gallery will not directly use your directory structure, but you can for example upload from server. Gallery is highly extendable and you can customize the views.

http://codex.gallery2.org/Category:Gallery_3:Modules

With native directory views (coming with nearly any webservers) you will not have a file description or thumbnails.